# Is there a way to use the Component's setSameWidth function on Codename One Designer?

Tags: codenameone

I've been wondering about this, and I hope I'm not missing something obvious, but I have a gripe with `Codename One Designer` for some time now. I find the `Component.setSameWidth()` function very useful to design a Form, however, I can only use it if I design it in code. When I try to design a Form on the Designer I usually run into situations where that feature would be very helpful.

Is there a way to use that feature, or similar, in `Codename One Designer`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

You can use the `beforeShow` event and invoke `setSameWidth` manually.

We are looking at adding this to the next version of the designer which will be a rewrite from the ground up.

Comment: I know this is an old thread but I am asking here to keep it relevant, is this still going to be added to the new GUI Builder?